# Textbox mask allow number only

Tags: jquery

I'm using textbox masked came from http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/. What I need to do is allow only numbers without limit length.

Just like here http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

```
Default Mask Legend
0: Only Numbers.
9: Only Numbers but optional.
#: Only Numbers but recusive.
A: Numbers and Letters.
S: Only A-Z and a-z characters.
```

If it is possible to do on this masked plugin http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a mask to do this. A simple JS function to run on your input element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});});
```

Simply change "#txtboxToFilter" to the ID of your text element, ex. #MyTextBox